# Taxes: Form 1116 income is both Passive and Treaty

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, foreign-income

Mostly valid for Americans living abroad.

I have income that qualifies as both Passive and Treaty (triple taxation) and would appreciate any advice as to whether I can claim both credits.

The background:
I am a US citizen living in the Netherlands, and have ETFs domiciled in the US. Some of these ETFs invest in non-US companies (e.g., IXUS). There are three forms of taxation on the non-US ETFs: the US taxes the income at 20% or more; the Netherlands taxes (there is a tax treaty that limits US tax to 15%); and other foreign countries tax (which shows up on my 1099-DIV).

- I know how to credit the amount taxed over 15% in the US (form 1116 Certain income re-sourced by treaty)
- I know how to credit the amount taxed on 1099-DIV (form 1116 Passive income)
- I don't know how to credit both at once, as I suspect it is not ok to claim the same income on two different 1116 forms.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Sean